# Rails 4.1 Elastic Beanstalk cannot find image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've uploaded a simple landing page to AWS elastic beanstalk based on Rails 4.1.

The problem is now the images are not being loaded.

```
http://localhost/assets/image.png shows me the image.
http://webinsight.co/assets/image.png does not exist.
```

When I look in AWS S3, the image files are uploaded properly to AWS.

Anybody else encountered the same problem before?

My site:
http://webinsight.co

Comment: You say 'when I look in AWS S3, the image files are uploaded properly' - What does an address to one of these images look like?

Comment: uploaded properly as in I can see the files in app/assets/images folder. Elastic Beanstalk auto zips each git commit, so the whole commit files are stored in 1 zip file. I can see the images files in this zip file. Image url is something like "localhost/assets/image.png"

Comment: You may not want to do this, but it could help with troubleshooting: Have you tried precompiling your assets?  Set `config.assets.compile = true` within your `application.rb` file.  If that doesn't help -- How are you trying to display the images?  Are you using a helper? Have you tried changing (if it is not already) your helper to read this instead: `image_tag image_path('image.png')`.  I tried a bunch of different urls on your site and can't seem to get anything to point to them, so this may not solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but both didn't work for me. Appreciate your help anyways.

Comment: You got the problem solved, you should answer the question yourself so others know how you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did that worked.

I changed all my image paths from "/assets/image.png" to

```
<%= image_tag("image.png") %>
```

For background images I changed it to something like

```
background: url(image-path('image.png')) no-repeat center center;
```

Then I did an assets precompilation.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

As for why this is needed, I read somewhere that there's some permissions issues with AWS S3 serving images if they are not listed in public/assets/ folder for rails projects.

Since assets:precompile automatically creates new instances of these images in the public folder, you don't have this issue after you do the changes and dynamically list the image path.

Comment: Or you can code more simply like this `background: image_url('image.png') no-repeat center center;`